# Templates: how to pass a non-type argument object as a non-type argument to another template

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

To avoid passing to many constants on an 8 bit system but still keep the code modular, I use templates with non-type (reference) arguments receiving those constants. This works without problems as long as I only pass the parameter object "one level" deep.

If I try to use such a templated object as a non type argument to another template, the compiler refuses my attempts even to declare such a template:

```
struct Params {constexpr Params(int i){}};
extern constexpr Params const p(1);

// This compiles fine
template <Params const &p> class A { };
A<p> a;

// This does not compile
template <A<Params const &> &a> class B { };
B<a> b;
```

So my question is: does anybody know how to define a template that receives an object of another (non-type) template as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `A` to be a template with a non-type parameter `p` (of type `Params const&`) but then in the definition of `B` you are passing a *type* to the template `A` (namely the type `Params const&`). You're treating `A` like it has a type parameter even though it doesn't.

But this works fine:

```
template <A<p> &a> class B { };
B<a> b;
```

If you want `B` to accept an argument of type `A<P>` for *any* `P`, then you need an extra template argument for `P`.

```
template <Params const& P, A<P> &a> class B { };
B<p, a> b;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which obviously solves the problem described in the question. The only flaw is the redundancy imposed by specifying the `p` twice - although the compiler can check it.

Comment: @kandid Yeah, I'm not too happy about that either. But I couldn't think of a workaround for this case. It's different when you have a type argument, because then you can use a specialization.